# Do we really need a tag for "vermin"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'll be honest this is mostly just because I dislike the word itself, but..

We currently have 5 questions (1 is on hold) using the [vermin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermin) tag:

- https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/how-can-i-get-rid-of-cooing-pigeons
- [Can I use a gecko to get rid of a cockroach infestation?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/can-i-use-a-gecko-to-get-rid-of-a-cockroach-infestation)
- [How can cat owners protect cats from secondary poisoning from rodenticides?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/how-can-cat-owners-protect-cats-from-secondary-poisoning-from-rodenticides)
- [How can I protect my chickens' eggs from snakes?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-can-i-protect-my-chickens-eggs-from-snakes)
- [How can I keep vermin out of outdoor pen or enclosure?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/273/how-can-i-keep-vermin-out-of-outdoor-pen-or-enclosure)

I think it's pretty clear that people using the tag view it as a [pest-control](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest-control) tag. The problem is that we are supposed to be about Pets not Pests. I'm simply not interested in helping people get rid of animals they don't like.

My solution is that we get rid of the tag so that we can get rid of the obviously off-topic questions, and discourage more questions from happening in the future (hopefully).

I think that for the question to be on-topic here it will be able to be tagged with other tags such as [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) if it's a case of pests causing the animal harm, or [parasites](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parasites) if it's a a parasite such as a flea or tick.

Otherwise I think that we should make a tag for [pest-control](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest-control) and make [vermin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermin) a synonym. At the very least, I think we need to rewrite the wiki for the [vermin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermin) tag so that it's more clear what it's supposed to be about.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: The last two feel entirely appropriate as questions for this site, but are, as you suggest in your question, much more aligned with [tag:pet-safety] than pest control within the scope of this site. Whether we need two safety tags - one for the pets themselves and one for us - is a separate question, but one we should possibly also consider.

Comment: I don't agree with requiring questions to be able to be tagged safety. There was nothing inherently dangerous about the Cheyletiella mite, but it was annoying (caused itching and sores), and it would be a case for pest-control.

Comment: Also, I'm okay with questions that ask "how can I get rid of this animal that's affecting my pet", but NOT "how can I get rid of this animal that's affecting me"

Comment: @Zaralynda I think mites would fall under the parasites tag. I guess I don't normally think of parasites and pests as the same even though they really are.

Comment: I've added a [tag:pest-control] tag and merged [tag:vermin] into it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm okay with a tag [pest-control](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest-control) that [vermin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermin) is a synonym for, though I don't have anything in particular against the term as it can be appropriate. My assumption would be, for the most part, that anyone asking about vermin would be in the context of pest control.

At any rate, as Zaralynda noted in the comments, I don't see that this should be merged into any [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) styled tag or the like. While it's true that some vermin pose a safety issue, it's not true that all of them do. I also agree that the issue needs to be related to pets, not to us.