# Do we need to separate [pet-safety] from [safety]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/810/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-vermin) about [vermin](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermin) made me wonder whether we should have separate tags for

- questions relating to the safety of pets
- questions about human safety in the presence of pets

The current [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) says that it's:

> For safety issues concerning the safety of pets, and also the safety of people from a pet.

and goes on to say:

> Issues about keeping pets safe, within the environment, and with basic care. Also about issue about an aggressive pet and the safety of people with that pet.

There are currently only 38 questions tagged with it, so it's certainly not an urgent question, but at what point and on what criteria would we decide "you know what, yes, we need to split them"?

And would it be premature to separate them now while the numbers are small enough that they could be easily enough scanned manually?

Comment: I'm kind of thinking that questions about human safety in the presence of pets might be off-topic. Or not different enough to need a different tag.

Comment: @MattS. disagree that human safety is off topic. Human safety addresses selecting training methods that will not cause a dog to become more aggressive (positive vs negative reinforcement), how to train a dog who is a known biter, etc. It wouldn't include how to treat a bite (cat, dog, snake, whatever).

Comment: Treating a snake bite, agreed, but noting how to minimise the risk of getting bitten should be on-topic, I'd argue.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tag is fine as it is.

The safety of pets is interrelated to their interactions with humans and, as Zaralynda just noted, can encompass proper training of more dangerous animals to ensure that human handlers are not injured. Heck, it can include proper training of humans in the handling of dangerous pets too! Splitting the tag into two doesn't really help anyone, I think.